# javascript I don't know how to get a specific object with getItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, local-storage

I want to get only accessToken value 123 inside Object in value in localStorage . I don't know how to get it.

```
key : stackoverflow 

value : 
{
  "accessToken": "123",
  "expiresAt": "2022-07-20T03:13:31.736756085Z",
  "refreshToken": "456"
}
```

I've tried it myself and it doesn't work.

```
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("stackoverflow", 'accessToken'))
```

Isn't this the way to get it?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What happens when you do? How does that differ from what you expected? Was there an error? How did you store the value into the storage in the first place? Notably, `localStorage` only ever stores strings; it is not possible to have an "Object in value in localStorage".

Comment: Get all expires, accessToken, refreshToken, not just access token value.

Comment: good to read resource for you. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the object as a JSON

```js
// SET
localStorage.setItem('stackoverflow', JSON.stringify(stackoverflow));
```

Then get it and parse it

```js
// GET
let stackoverflow = localStorage.getItem('stackoverflow');
stackoverflow = JSON.parse(stackoverflow);
```

And finally you can get the property of `stackoverflow` object

```js
const accessToken = stackoverflow.accessToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the value saved as `json` so you need to parse it first using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) like this

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("stackoverflow"))
console.log(parsedData.accessToken)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before saving the data, you must convert an object into a string, because localstorage only support **string** type, and whenever you want to get that object data, you must parse that data and then you can access object data

```
localStorage.setItem(
      'stackoverflow',
      JSON.stringify({
        accessToken: '123',
        expiresAt: '2022-07-20T03:13:31.736756085Z',
        refreshToken: '456',
      })
);
const stackoverflow: any = localStorage.getItem('stackoverflow');  
const obj = JSON.parse(stackoverflow);
console.log(obj.accessToken);
```